# How to route mssql traffic through an Istio egress gateway

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, istio-gateway

I am trying to run a .Net 6 demonstration application in an Istio service mesh (Istio 1.16.1 in an AKS cluster). This application uses a sqlserver 2019 located outside the cluster and I would like to route all outgoing traffic, including mssql, through an egress gateway.
Please note this application also use OpenId Connect and use keytabs (Kerberos traffic), I have successfully managed to route those requests through the egress gateway but not the mssql traffic.

I have created the service mesh with istioctl and the following configuration file

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  profile: default
  meshConfig:
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
    enableTracing: true
    defaultConfig:
      tracing:
        sampling: 100
    outboundTrafficPolicy:
      mode: REGISTRY_ONLY
  components:
    pilot:
      k8s:
        nodeSelector:
          agentpool: svcmaster
    ingressGateways:
      - name: istio-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          nodeSelector:
            kubernetes.io/os: linux
    egressGateways:
      - name: istio-egressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          nodeSelector:
            kubernetes.io/os: linux
```

Here is the ServiceEntry for the database

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: mssql-contoso-com
  namespace: linux
spec:
  hosts:
    - mssql.contoso.com
  addresses:
    - 10.1.0.5
  ports:
    - number: 1433
      name: mssql
      protocol: TLS
    - number: 443
      name: tls
      protocol: TLS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  resolution: DNS
```

Here is the gateway (it includes the host

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: egress-gateway
  namespace: linux
spec:
  selector:
    istio: egressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 443
        name: tls
        protocol: TLS
      hosts:
        - "adfs.contoso.com"
        - "mssql.contoso.com"
      tls:
        mode: "PASSTHROUGH"
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: tcp
        protocol: TCP
      hosts:
        - "controller.contoso.com"
```

And finally, the VirtualService. I have not defined a DestinationRule because it is actually useless, the OIDC and Kerberos traffic are routed correctly without them and I have tried to add it out of desperation without solving the issue.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: "outgoing-mssql-traffic"
  namespace: linux
spec:
  hosts:
    - mssql.contoso.com
  gateways:
    - egress-gateway
    - mesh
  tls:
    - match:
        - gateways:
            - mesh
          port: 1433
          sniHosts:
            - mssql.contoso.com
      route:
        - destination:
            host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 443
          weight: 100
    - match:
        - gateways:
            - egress-gateway
          port: 443
          sniHosts:
            - mssql.contoso.com
      route:
        - destination:
            host: mssql.contoso.com
            port:
              number: 1433
          weight: 100
```

Regarding the details of the application call to the SQL Server, I am using a regular SQLConnection with the following connection string:

```
Server=mssql.contoso.com;Initial Catalog=Demonstration;Integrated Security=true;TrustServerCertificate=true
```

As a result, I get the following error in the application log:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (104): Connection reset by peer
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
```

Somehow the TLS handshake fails. When consulting the logs of the sidecar container and of the egress gateway, I cannot see the traffic to the database. I have also monitored the traffic on the SQLServer machine with Wireshark and I cannot see TCP traffic on port 1433.

The application works fine when the virtual service is deleted so the issue is really related to the routing through the egress gateway.

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So I found out the reason a bit by accident while trying different configurations and checking the Envoy logs. The Istio Egress gateway service exposes only two ports (at least by default): 80 and 443. It seems that each port can only serve one VirtualService and it is first come first served. I had declared the VirtualService for mssql last, so it was not served.

Furthermore, I had to switch to a TCP route. I failed to get it working with a TLS route.

Here is the ServiceEntry:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: mssql-contoso-com
  namespace: linux
spec:
  hosts:
    - mssql.contoso.com
  addresses:
    - 10.1.0.5
  ports:
    - number: 1433
      name: mssql
      protocol: TCP
    - number: 80
      name: tls
      protocol: TCP
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  resolution: DNS
```

And here is the VirtualService:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: "outgoing-mssql-traffic"
  namespace: linux
spec:
  hosts:
    - mssql.contoso.com
  gateways:
    - egress-gateway
    - mesh
  tcp:
    - match:
        - gateways:
            - mesh
          port: 1433
      route:
        - destination:
            host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 80
          weight: 100
    - match:
        - gateways:
            - egress-gateway
          port: 80
      route:
        - destination:
            host: mssql.contoso.com
            port:
              number: 1433
          weight: 100
```

I guess that I will have to either deploy several egress gateways or find a way to add ports to the existing one.